# Connect to Azure VM, SQL database, etc... using corporate login

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

Discovering Azure as I am starting a new job, I created an Office 365 account that has my domain. The email address is name@company.com, and we are three people with this kind of email address/login.

We use the same credentials to log in the Azure portal. I created a couple of VMs and a couple of databases in Azure, but the only way to access them is through the admin user that I had to create when I set the VMs and databases up in Azure.

I don't manage to make the three of us using our name@company.com (or COMPANY\name) with our own passwords to log in the VM or database.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Not exactly sure what your question is. You're trying to connect to a SQL Database instance with your Azure login?

Comment: yes, and same for virtual machines. The SQL database is an azure SQL db, thus it has an admin login in Azure which i had to create when i created the azure SQL db. Same goes with the Virtual machines in created in the Azure Portal

Answer (score 0):

A solution was found for SQL databases. SSMS 2014 does not show Active Directory password authentication, while 2016 does. So installing SSMS 2016 did solve the problem.

The problem remains for VM though. I don't manage to give access to the Active Directory users to the virtual machines.

Comment: do your servers belong to the domain? and more important do you have ADFS in place? as i suspect you think that AAD and AD are the same which isn't quite true. Server management is done on Server evel not on Azure Level ... depending on how you want to connect this could be achieved in many different ways

Comment: i created one VM to be a Domain Controller, i also installed Azure AD Connect on that machine (not sure about what that actually does though...). 
My second VM is joined to the same domain, then users maintained on the DC can access that VM based on the rights i gave them from the DC. 
But now i don't have a centralized place for managing my users, as my Azure SQL databases users are part of a group i created in Azure active directory portal, whil my VM users are part of groups/users i created on the Domain controller server. I would like to manage everything from a unique place

Comment: I thought Azure Active Directory was that unique place, but it seems i misunderstood how it actually works